# PHP number_format with only minimum decimal digits

Tags: php, numbers

How to set minimum decimal digits but not maximum decimal digits. I tried with `number_format` but the results were unexpected.

```php
<?php

echo number_format("1000000", 2) . "<br>";
echo number_format("1000000.6", 2) . "<br>";
echo number_format("1000000.63", 2) . "<br>";
echo number_format("1000000.68464", 2) . "<br>";

?>
```

Result:

```
1,000,000.00
1,000,000.60
1,000,000.63
1,000,000.68
```

Expected Result:

```
1,000,000.00
1,000,000.60
1,000,000.63
1,000,000.68464
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a more advanced class called [`NumberFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) which is part of the intl extension that supports both minimum and maximum, and you can just set the latter to a high number to achieve your expected results.

```php
$f = new NumberFormatter('en-US', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$f->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
$f->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 999);
echo $f->format("1000000") . PHP_EOL;
echo $f->format("1000000.6") . PHP_EOL;
echo $f->format("1000000.63") . PHP_EOL;
echo $f->format("1000000.68464") . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
1,000,000.00
1,000,000.60
1,000,000.63
1,000,000.68464
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/filso#v8.0.25

Answer (score 0):

Simple function for that. You can custom function for your idea: string to use for decimal point,...

```
function number_format_min_precision($v, $minPrecision) {
 $curentPrecision = strlen(explode('.', $v)[1] ?? 0);
 if ($curentPrecision < $minPrecision) return number_format($v, $minPrecision);
  return $v;
}
echo number_format_min_precision('1000000', 2) . PHP_EOL;
echo number_format_min_precision('1000000.6', 2) . PHP_EOL;
echo number_format_min_precision('1000000.63', 2) . PHP_EOL;
echo number_format_min_precision('1000000.68464', 2) . PHP_EOL;
```

Results:

```
1,000,000.00
1,000,000.60
1000000.63
1000000.68464
```